# script for substition incremental

Tags: bash, scripting

I have 4 machines, every machine(centos) has a ifcfg-bond1 with identical ip address 10.0.0.3
How to using bash and sed substituting 10.0.0.3 with a incremental value?
I want to obtain something like this

```
machine1        -> 10.0.0.1
machine2        -> 10.0.0.2
machine3        -> 10.0.0.3
machine4        -> 10.0.0.4
```

I have tried a script with let and bash on ssh but for all machine i get 10.0.0.2(using let+1)

```
for i in machine{1..4};do ssh $i "var=1;export var;let var=var+1;echo 10.0.0.$var";done
```

Any suggestion?Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question, but I guess you are trying to do `for i in machine{1..4};do ssh $i "echo 10.0.0.$i";done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in {1..4};do ssh machine$i "echo 10.0.0.$i";done
```

In this code I keep the numbers separate for a bit longer: I only have the number, not the word machine. I then use it to create the address of the machine for `ssh` and for the echo.

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain better,i have five machines,i want to increase by one a variable
i have tried ssh -t

```
for i in eracle{1..5};do ssh -t $i 'var="1";export var;var=$((var + 1));echo $var';done
2
Connection to eracle1 closed.
2
Connection to eracle2 closed.
2
Connection to eracle3 closed.
2
Connection to eracle4 closed.
2
Connection to eracle5 closed.
```

I want to obtain 2,3,4,5.